# create a dictionary using 2 lists using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a dictionary from 2 lists where one list contains keys and one list contains values. I can do it using for loop but I am trying to find if there is a way of doing it using LINQ.
Sample code will be helpfull. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In .NET4 you could use the built-in [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28VS.100%29.aspx) method to merge the two sequences, followed by a [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary%28VS.100%29.aspx) call:

```
var keys = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var values = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };

var dictionary = keys.Zip(values, (k, v) => new { Key = k, Value = v })
                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 21):

```
        List<string> keys = new List<string>();
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = keys.ToDictionary(x => x, x => values[keys.IndexOf(x)]);
```

This of course assumes that the length of each list is the same and that the keys are unique.

**UPDATE:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2434647/258809) is far more efficient and should be used for lists of non-trivial size.

Comment: I'd rather use a loop, instead of using this. Still +1 for the answer.

Comment: why would you use loops instead of LINQ? I thought this code is lot more succint and readable than the for loop.

Comment: Because with the code above it has to do a linear search for the element x in the List<strign> of keys for every key (In O(n) time).  In a loop the index is known at each iteration so no search is necessary.

Comment: As @PaulRuane points out, but I think is worth stressing since this is the top answer, this solution is very inefficient and a potential and totally unnecessary bottleneck that you should avoid. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2434647/167251) instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can include the index in a `Select` expression to make this efficient:

```
        var a = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
        var b = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };

        var c = a.Select((x, i) => new {key = x, value = b[i]}).ToDictionary(e => e.key, e => e.value );

        foreach (var d in c)
            Console.WriteLine(d.Key + " = " + d.Value);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dic = keys.Zip(values, (k, v) => new { k, v })
          .ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
```

Comment: Does this really add anything to [LukeH](http://stackoverflow.com/users/55847/lukeh)'s [5 year-old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2434647/215380)?

Answer (score -3):

You can use this code and working perfectly.

C# Code:

```
  var keys = new List<string> { "Kalu", "Kishan", "Gourav" };
        var values = new List<string> { "Singh", "Paneri", "Jain" };

        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
        {

            dictionary.Add(keys[i].ToString(), values[i].ToString());
        }
        foreach (var data in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", data.Key, data.Value);

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Output Screen:

[image]

Comment: Too cumbersome a task