# Match groups in set at most once

Tags: .net, regex

I want to use regular expressions to validate strings that are like this:

```
foo.bar=123.baz=456.qux=789.urr
```

(where `123`, `456`, and `789` are placeholders arbitrary numbers, but `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, `qux` and `urr` is literal text and not placeholders. I need to capture the values of `bar`/`baz`/`qux` individually so I'm using named capture groups.

The problem is that `bar=a`, `baz=b` and `qux=c` are entirely optional and can appear in any order. So my regular expression needs to accept these as valid:

```
foo.urr
foo.bar=123.urr
foo.qux=123.bar=456.urr
foo.baz=123.bar=456.qux=789.urr
```

...but reject these as invalid:

```
foo.bar=123.bar=456.urr
foo.qux=123.baz=456.qux=789.urr
```

My regular expression code is this for now:

```
const String Bar = @"(?<bar>bar=(\d)+)";
const String Baz = @"(?<baz>baz=(\d)+)";
const String Qux = @"(?<qux>qux=(\d)+)";

const String Regex = @"^foo\.((" + Bar + "|" + Baz + "|" + Qux + @")\.)*urr$";
```

My expression uses `*` to allow for the optional `Bar`, `Baz` and `Qux` named-groups in any order but it also allows them to appear multiple times, which should not be allowed.

I know I could brute-force it with `n!` expressions, but in future the number of these elements could expand over time and that wouldn't be possible to hard-code.

#### Update:

I could have used a better example in my original question, but the values of `bar`, `baz` and `qux` all have their own sub-expressions, e.g. `bar` accepts hexadecimal digits, `baz` accepts decimal digits, and `qux` accepts alphabetical characters-only, so this is invalid:

```
foo.bar=zzz.baz=aaa.qux=123.urr
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use multiple regex patterns and some simple logic in between? Or in fact a single regex that captures everything in the form `xxx=000`, then do the checks about not repeating the strings in code?

Comment: @BenAaronson I could, but that would drastically increase the complexity. Can you give an example of how I would use that approach in a manageable way?

Comment: It would probably make the code (outside the regular expression) more complex but at the same time it would make the regular expression easier. Don't forget that the regular expression has to be parsed/applied as well. It's not like it's one single instruction just due to being one single line in your code.

Comment: Is `foo.bar=123.xxx=456.urr` invalid (`xxx` variable is not in the list)?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Yes, it's invalid as the names can only be `bar`, `baz` or `qux`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^foo(?:\.(?<name>bar|baz|qux)=(?<value>\d+)(?!.*\k<name>))*.urr$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Sample code:

```
string[] lines = {
    "foo.urr",
    "foo.bar=123.urr",
    "foo.qux=123.bar=456.urr",
    "foo.baz=123.bar=456.qux=789.urr",
    "foo.bar=123.bar=456.urr",
    "foo.qux=123.baz=456.qux=789.urr"
};
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(line, @"^foo(?:\.(?<name>bar|baz|qux)=(?<value>\d+)(?!.*\k<name>))*.urr$");
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", line, m.Success);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.Groups["name"].Captures.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}",
                              m.Groups["name"].Captures[i].Value,
                              m.Groups["value"].Captures[i].Value);
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
foo.urr : True
foo.bar=123.urr : True
bar = 123
foo.qux=123.bar=456.urr : True
qux = 123
bar = 456
foo.baz=123.bar=456.qux=789.urr : True
baz = 123
bar = 456
qux = 789
foo.bar=123.bar=456.urr : False
foo.qux=123.baz=456.qux=789.urr : False
```

**UPDATE**

Each group has to have a name. Then we can make the following principle: if A, B, C are given, then ABC repeated 3 times will give all possible combinations, i.e. `(A?B?C?){3}`. Then we just need negative lookahead so that there is no other matching A if it is already matched.

```
^foo(?:(?:.bar=(?<bar>\d+)(?!.*\.bar))?(?:.baz=(?<baz>\d+)(?!.*\.baz))?(?:.qux=(?<qux>\d+)(?!.*\.qux))?){0,3}.urr$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Sample code:

```
string[] lines = {
    "foo.urr",
    "foo.bar=123.urr",
    "foo.qux=123.bar=456.urr",
    "foo.baz=123.bar=456.qux=789.urr",
    "foo.bar=123.bar=456.urr",
    "foo.qux=123.baz=456.qux=789.urr"
};
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(line, @"^foo((?:.bar=(?<bar>\d+)(?!.*\.bar))?(?:.baz=(?<baz>\d+)(?!.*\.baz))?(?:.qux=(?<qux>\d+)(?!.*\.qux))?){0,3}.urr$");
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", line, m.Success);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        Group bar = m.Groups["bar"];
        if (bar.Success)
            Console.WriteLine("bar = {0}", bar.Value);
        Group baz = m.Groups["baz"];
        if (baz.Success)
            Console.WriteLine("baz = {0}", baz.Value);
        Group qux = m.Groups["qux"];
        if (qux.Success)
            Console.WriteLine("qux = {0}", qux.Value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
foo.urr : True
foo.bar=123.urr : True
bar = 123
foo.qux=123.bar=456.urr : True
bar = 456
qux = 123
foo.baz=123.bar=456.qux=789.urr : True
bar = 456
baz = 123
qux = 789
foo.bar=123.bar=456.urr : False
foo.qux=123.baz=456.qux=789.urr : False
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but I should have made clear in my original question that in my specific case the same regex sub-expresssion cannot for `bar`, `baz`, and `qux`'s value simultaneously, sorry.

Comment: I think you're on-to something! :) It's almost 4am here so I'm going to bed but I'll try this out in the morning, thank you so far! :D

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for an example, here's an approach where you capture all strings in the correct format:

```
^foo\.(?:([a-zA-Z]+)\=(\d+)\.)*urr$
```

There are two numbered capture groups, so in your example `foo.baz=123.bar=456.qux=789.urr`, the matches will be as follows:

```
0: baz, bar, qux
1: 123, 456, 789
```

Handling this in code is relatively straightforward. So for example:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"^foo\.(?:([a-zA-Z]+)\=(\d+)\.)*urr$");
var test = "foo.baz=123.bar=456.qux=789.urr";
var match = reg.Match(test);
return match.Groups[0].Captures.Count == match.Groups[0].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Distinct();
```

This will return true if there are no duplicate strings as you described and false otherwise.

As another example of processing in code, you can also quite easily turn the two collections of captures into a dictionary with the technique described, e.g., here: [create a dictionary using 2 lists using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434593/create-a-dictionary-using-2-lists-using-linq)

Also note that if you want to specify the keys in the regex, you can replace the `[a-zA-Z]+` with the individual strings you want to match like `baz|bar|qux`. Alternatively you can check that in code too.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but I should have made clear in my original question that in my specific case the same regex sub-expresssion cannot for `bar`, `baz`, and `qux`'s value simultaneously, sorry.

Comment: @Dai Okay, well my suggestion in that case would be to give a more general expression for that part (e.g. `.*`), then do that validation in code. Generally pushing that sort of thing to code makes your solution more readable and maintainable.